# Convert a list of strings to a list of templatized strings

Tags: python, string, list

My main requirement is to add a template to list of strings and join them as a single string .

```
def give_str(input_list, template, delimiter="()", joiner=""):
    #Some operation happens here
    return output_string

Input: give_str(["first", "second", "third"], ["count", "rank"], delimiter="()", joiner=",")
Output: "count(rank(first)),count(rank(second)),count(rank(third))"
```

Right now, I am doing something like this:

```
def give_str(input_list, template, delimiter="()", joiner=","):
    output_string = ""
    template_string = delimiter[0].join(template) + delimiter[0]
    item_close = delimiter[-1] * len(template)
    output_string = joiner.join(template_string+item+item_close for item in input_list if item)
    return output_string
```

I am not happy with multiple string additions even though this is simple and straight forward. Is there any built-in library(only built-in as I cannot install any 3rd party packages) which can simplify this process? Simplifying in the sense of

One more thing which is implied is that delimiter is either a single character or a double character. Possible delimiters: ",", "|", "()", "[]",...

NOTE: Please give a comment on why you view this as useless, if you down vote. I & Someone who may come to this question in future may learn a thing or two with your view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cleaner approach would be to use [string.template](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Template)

```
>>> from string import Template
>>> def give_str(input_list, template, delimiter="()", joiner=""):
    s = Template("$temp$left$inner$right")
    data = []
    for elem in input_list:
        for t in reversed(template):
            elem = s.substitute(
                temp=t,
                left = delimiter[0],
                right = delimiter[-1],
                inner = elem)
        data.append(elem)
    return joiner.join(data)

>>> give_str(["first", "second", "third"], ["count", "rank"], delimiter="()", joiner=",")
'count(rank(first)),count(rank(second)),count(rank(third))'
>>> give_str(["first", "second", "third"], ["count", "rank"], delimiter="|", joiner=",")
'count|rank|first||,count|rank|second||,count|rank|third||'
```

Answer (score 1):

Readability is of course subjective. This is the most 'readable' version I could get to:

```
def give_str(input_list, template, delimiter="()", joiner=","):
    if len(delimiter) == 2:
        pattern = "TEMPLATE{0}INPUT{1}".format(delimiter[0], delimiter[1])
    else:
        pattern = "TEMPLATE{0}INPUT{0}".format(delimiter)
    final_list = input_list
    for tmp in reversed(template):
        final_list = [pattern.replace("TEMPLATE", tmp).replace("INPUT", x) for x in final_list]
    return joiner.join(final_list)
```

Comment: Nice one. We can remove the if... else with pattern = "TEMPLATE{0}INPUT{1}".format(delimiter[0], delimiter[-1])

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand what you want done, and I don't know of any core library that does what you want... if you want it to be very efficient you can of course code the function in C and expose it to the python API (it is much easier than you might think)...

with regardes to the delimiter having both 1 and 2 length, is this what you want:

```
def give_str(input_list, template, delimiter="()", joiner=","):
    output_string =  item_close = ""
    template_string = delimiter[0].join(template) + delimiter[0]
    if len(delimiter) == 2:
        item_close += delimiter[1] * len(template)
    output_string = joiner.join(template_string+item+item_close for item in input_list if item)
    return output_string

In [10]: give_str(["first", "second", "third"], ["count", "rank"], delimiter="()", joiner=",")
Out[10]: 'count(rank(first)),count(rank(second)),count(rank(third))'

In [11]: give_str(["first", "second", "third"], ["count", "rank"], delimiter=";", joiner=",")
Out[11]: 'count;rank;first,count;rank;second,count;rank;third'
```

for out speed debate (see comments)

```
In [70]: d = 'd' * (10 **8)
In [71]: c = 'c' * (10 **8)
In [72]: b = 'b' * (10 **8)
In [73]: a = 'a' * (10 **8)


In [92]: %timeit ''.join((a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d))
1 loops, best of 3: 778 ms per loop

In [93]: %timeit a+b+c+d+a+b+c+d+a+b+c+d
1 loops, best of 3: 662 ms per loop
```

I would expect ''.join to be up to 10 times faster... but it seems not to be

Comment: I am not looking for a faster way. I am looking for a cleaner/ more readable way, if any. More like make a template and pass string list as an argument.

Comment: ok, then I misunderstood you :), as my second attempt I tried to use StringIO to write to a buffer to see if that was faster, but that was 4 times slower :)... go with Abhijit solution then :)

Comment: I was told once that nothing can beat the + operation in case of merging/concatenating strings in speed :-) Besides [Premature optimization](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DubiousPython#Premature_Optimization) is the root of all evil ;-)

Comment: @thiruvenkadam, you are right!, (I just tested it), I always assumed that for insaintly long strings ''.join would be faster as xyz = x+y+z is the same as xy = x + y; xyz = xy + z, and I assumed that join was implemented as a c function, thus doing the computation in one fell swoop... that does not seem to be the case however...

Comment: Actually join is lot faster for adding many big strings than +=, as strings are immutable in python. Try with more than 400+ characters string,  and you will be surprised that join is lot faster than + as well as += :-)

Comment: @thiruvenkadam I have always believed join to be faster for large strings, but after you said that '+' was fastest I tested it on large strings (see code above), and + is still faster for 10^8 long strings